# zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header caused by zip caching bug?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I'm trying to determine if there is still a bug in the zip caching mechanism used by python. The reason is because my running python code will (seemingly) randomly fail with `zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header`.

It could be running along fine and then all of a sudden, `ZipImportError` when it tries to import a custom module I've installed (this can happen when it's already run this same code earlier in the execution). I'm not changing the egg file of the custom module while the application is running so I'm kind of stumped.

Googling for help with this error turned up [an old mailing list thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2009-February/010971.html) which states

> This might be due to:
>
> http://bugs.python.org/issue856103
>
> Specifically, zipimport's caching doesn't notice that it's not 
>   working on the same zipfile any more.  easy_install is supposed to 
>   have some code in it to clear out the zipimport cache, but there is 
>   some possibility that it could have two versions of the path in there 
>   on a case-insensitive filesystem (e.g. Windows), and only one of them 
>   is getting cleared.  Dunno if that's the case or not, but it might be 
>   something to look into.  You could always stick a debugging print in 
>   the uncache_zipdir function and see if there's any correlation 
>   between what it's doing and when you're getting the error.

The resolution of the linked bug is unclear to me.

I think the only way to solve my problem at this point is to mark my custom module as `zip_safe=false`. Unless there's some way to disable zip caching or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the cause or fix for this issue but I changed my module to use `zip_safe=false` and that prevented the problem from happening again. In my case, that was good enough.